# How can I speed up window switching on windows 10 when too many processes are started?

Tags: windows-10

I have about 270-350 processes running on windows 10. The 2core CPU is loaded about 30%. So when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> I have a delay with 3-5 second to see opened windows.

Is there a way to speedup this? What process or service is responsible for showing menu on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>? (may be problem can be solved by increasing priority for that process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number of processes is just a little too much for your CPU. Get a beefier computer. That is the only real solution.
(The load figure of 30% doesn't say much. It is the overhead in task-switching which is the problem, which isn't really reflected in the load-figure.)
I frequently run some 800+ processes, with over 10.000 threads in total. That is a struggle even for my 8-core (16 if you count hyper-threading) Xeon workstation, even though load is only shown at 40-45% in Task Manager in my case.

Having said that... Boosting process priority won't make much difference in my experience.

Ctrl-tab/alt-tab handling is handled by Explorer.exe, but it interacts with all the other processes, while it is doing that. So boosting explorer might actually makes things worse (your mileage may vary, this is impossible to predict), because it will skew WiIndows own sense of process/thread balancing over the cores.
And given Explorer.exe a boost might have serious side-effects. Explorer (being essentially the windows-manager) has its fingers in may too many stuff as it is. Giving it more priority (or less for that matter) might have some weird side-effects in other places in Windows.

You can give it a try, you can't really break anything (reboot will solve it if you do), but don't expect much benefit.